# Best practice for naming different contents(Ex:String and byte) which has similar reference(Ex:name)

Tags: java, naming-conventions

This is a simple best practice issue that I faced recently in a legacy code that I'm working these days. I couldn't find a good reference for this specific issue cause there can be multiple ways that we can achieve this. However, I would like to know the best and most effective way to achieve this. Below I have created some of my findings and I hope to get others opinion on what would be the best way to name naming different contents which has similar reference.

**Example 1**

```
String name = "Thushara";
byte[] nameByte = toBytes(name);
```

**Example 2**

```
String nameStr = "Thushara";
byte[] nameByte = toBytes(nameStr);
```

**Example 3**

```
String strName = "Thushara";
byte[] byteName = toBytes(strName);
```

I know there will not be a standard to achieve this. Therefore, I would like to know the best way to do this in maintainability or other perspective which I don't know.

---

**Update**

- ***Best Solution So far***

> ```
> String name = "Thushara"; 
> byte[] nameBytes = toBytes(name);
> ```

Comment: Usually I like to name arrays with an `s` at the end, so it would be `nameBytes`

Comment: I like to name arrays with a `z` at the end, so I am voting to close this post as being *primarily opinion based*

Comment: Do the variables have different scopes? For example, if the string is a class-level member but the byte array is local to a method on the class then I'd favor the intuitive name (in this case `name`) be given to the more important member (the string) and the more descriptive name (something like `nameBytes`) be given to the less important local variable. I'd also make the same suggestion based on the idea that a "name" is a string, so the string is more aptly described as `name`, while the byte array is an altered representation of that concept and could be named to reflect that (`nameBytes`).

Comment: Yes that a good practice. Thanks for the opinons. Looking forward to see more opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to escape from such decisions.

You have to rethink your code in case if you need to name differently objects of different type that represent the same entity. Most likely there is a design problem. Why do you need them both in the same scope? Can't you extract the logic which requires `byte[]` into separate method/class? Can you solve it using polymorphism? May be you can simply inline the call?

General rule is to name variables closer to domain model you have. `byteName` does not carry any valuable information and it should signal that something is wrong.

The only exception is unit testing. Obviously if you write unit test for `toBytes()` method you'll face this issue. But even in this case you can name objects `input` and `output`, `expected` and `actual` etc.

Once you think on this questions you'll come with idea on how to get rid of this.